# Splunk search a pattern for log like "Response Elapsed: 00:00:00.0594215"

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

There are some information like as following in my log:

> "
> .....Response Elapsed: 00:00:00.0194215....
>
> .....Response Elapsed: 00:00:05.0174875....
>
> .....Response Elapsed: 00:00:11.5434871....
>
> .....Response Elapsed: 00:00:01.342283....
> "

I want to search a result for  elapsed time > 5 seconds, in the above information , the result should be like

> Response Elapsed: 00:00:11.5434871
>
> Response Elapsed: 00:00:05.0174875

I tried "**| Regex "/^Response Elapsed: 00:00:00.0[5-9]/"**",but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easier to find a regular expression for the negative case than the positive one.  Your example regex could be made to work for 5-9 seconds, but what about a minute and 5-9 seconds, etc?  Try this:

```
... | regex _raw!="Response Elapsed: 00:00:0[0-4]\.\d+" | ...
```